# Is there a way to build a Dojo module that includes a single file from the package location?

Tags: javascript, build, dojo

I have the following build profile for a small app:

```
var profile = (function(){

    var copyOnly = function(filename, mid){
        /* ..snip.. */
    };

    return {
        basePath: "../../src",
        releaseDir: "../dist",
        releaseName: "lib",
        action: "release",

        packages: [
        'dojo',
        'dijit',
        //'dojox',
        'amd',
        {
            name: 'lodash',
            location: 'lodash',
            trees: [
                [".", ".", /(\/\.)|(~$)|(vendor|test)/]
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'd3',
            location: 'd3',
            main: 'd3.min',
            trees: [
                [".", ".", /(\/\.)|(~$)|(src|lib|test)/]
            ]
        },
        { name: 'app', location: 'app' }
    ],

        layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                include: [ "dojo/dojo", "amd/d3","amd/gmaps",
                    "app/main", "app/run" ],
                customBase: true,
                boot: true
            }
        },

        resourceTags: {
            /* ..snip.. */
        }
    };
})();
```

The problem is this: all I need is the lodash.min.js file to be processed by the Dojo build system. Unfortunately, when you include a package definition in your profile, the build system looks at *all* files in the relevant directory using an implicit `trees` value. You can overwrite it (as I have done here) and add some ignore directives, but this is ugly and leaves you open to missing something of. What I'd *like* to do is affirmatively indicate precisely which file(s) that I'm interested in processing for my build process.

Does Dojo allow you to do this? The documentation is a little scant in this area, but if you can help me find a resource that explains this more clearly, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.9 at least, I believe this can be done:

```
// ... snip ...
{
    name:'lodash',
    location:'lodash',
    trees:[],
    dirs:[],
    files:[
        ["lodash.min.js"]
    ]
},
```

This explicitly lists the files, while also squashing implicit tree and directory discovery.

My belief here is based on a cursory review of `util/build/discover.js` -- but as I read [the documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/buildSystem.html#trees-dirs-and-files) files only *should* be supported.